# How to get users permission without redirect to Facebook logo

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am developing a facebook application. When a new user uses the facebook link, the user is first redirected to a screen with facebook logo and then redirected to facebook permission screen immediately. How to avoid first redirection, ie. to facebook logo screen? I want to go directly to the facebook permission screen.

I am redirecting to the page using the code below:

```
 string authLink = string.Format(
                      "{0}?client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&scope={3}", 
                       new object[] 
                           { 
                              "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize", 
                              "APPID", 
                              "CallBackURL", 
                              FBPermissions.email + "," + 
                              FBPermissions.user_about_me + "," +
                              FBPermissions.user_birthday + "," +
                              FBPermissions.publish_stream + "," +
                              FBPermissions.user_status + "," + 
                              FBPermissions.user_photos 
                            }
                  );
    Response.Redirect(authLink);
```

I am developing the application with asp.net c#.
I am using graph api also. 
Please guide me how to achieve the above.

Thanks in advance.
Sujith.

Comment: Please format your code so that someone except you can read it

Comment: you says its forward to screen where facebook logo it looks you forwarding to facebook some  page i.e. your Fan page thats why you seeing this but the above code dosen't show any code for first redirection so please update your code

Comment: I have set the canvas url and secure canvas url to my server address. I have hosted my app into the server and from its default page i am calling the above lines of codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let me try to understand this better; you're trying to bypass the login, and re-direct them immediately to the permissions page? How would this work exactly? For new users facebook, as with any application that will affect permissions of any kind, needs to know what user they're dealing with. The redirection to the login page greatly depends on if the user is already authenticated on their machine. In short, there may be some occasions where the login page isn't "visited" by the user, and they are simply redirected to the permissions page, but this will depend on the user having already logged into facebook and saved their authentication, which can't be guaranteed.

Comment: No. Only after login the user can access the app. If he is not logged in, then he will be redirected to the login page.

Comment: That is exactly what my post explains. What are you trying to achieve? Your question conflicts your comment you just posted.

Comment: I didn't clearly understand what you mean. I will explain what is my problem. What my problem is:  In the search box, above facebook, i typed something, for eg: "TestApp". And assume that i got an app with that name. When clicking on that app, the user should redirect to the facebook app, which is hosted in some another machine. Now, what is happening is, when the user selects the app for the first time, he is redirecting to facebook logo, instead of permission page. I want to avoid that facebook logo screen.